# Android Market Statistics Problems

Tags: android, statistics, installation, google-play

I have recently uploaded two apps on the android market, with one already there previously. When I uploaded teh first I had statistics available almost instantly, however with the two that I uploaded last night, I still do not see a statistics link? Why is that?

And also the active installs doesnt seem to update even though the total installs shows some change. For example I have 21 total installs and ZERO active installs...Obviously this couldnt be right because its installed on two phones in my household.

Comment: Contact Google support. They probably have a better insight as to how/when are the stats updated.

Comment: Since the Android OS is not implemented the same by all manufacturers and even on all of manufacturer's phones, you need to provide information on your phone model and manufacturer to help us determine the source of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a temporary outage on market: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/tfjO8eDobZ4/discussion

Comment: I get an error clicking the link, but this seems to be the issue. Can you paste the information here? and i will tick this :)

Comment: It's a thread with 27 posts at this time and I have 548 character left. You might have to register on Google groups to see it. If you're in Android dev you should do this anyway. If you just want a confirmation, check this one: https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/static.py?page=known_issues.cs